# Verilog Illegal Reference to net 'OUT'

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I don't understand why my compiler is complaining about all of my assignment statements to OUT. Here is my code:

```
`include "prj_definition.v"
module ALU(OUT, ZERO, OP1, OP2, OPRN);
// input list
input [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] OP1; // operand 1
input [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] OP2; // operand 2
input [`ALU_OPRN_INDEX_LIMIT:0] OPRN; // operation code

// output list
output [`DATA_INDEX_LIMIT:0] OUT; // result of the operation.
output ZERO;

always @(OP1 or OP2 or OPRN)
begin
// TBD - Code for the ALU
case (OPRN)
        `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h01 : OUT = OP1 + OP2; // addition
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h02 : OUT = OP1 - OP2; // subtraction
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h03 : OUT = OP1 * OP2; // multiplication  
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h04 : OUT = OP1 >> OP2; // shift_right
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h05 : OUT = OP1 << OP2; // shift_left
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h06 : OUT = OP1 & OP2; // bitwise and
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h07 : OUT = OP1 | OP2; // bitwise or
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h08 : OUT = ~(OP1 | OP2); // bitwise nor
    `ALU_OPRN_WIDTH'h09 : OUT = OP1 < OP2; // less than

        default: OUT = `DATA_WIDTH'hxxxxxxxx;
endcase
end

always @(OUT) //whenever the output changes
begin
if(OUT === 0) ZERO = 1; //if result is 0, set the zero flag
else ZERO = 0; //otherwise keep the 0 flag false
end

endmodule
```

Could someone please explain what is going on? Let me know if more information is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Just in case anyone else is having a similar problem, here is what I added:

```
//output registers
output reg OUT;
output reg ZERO;
```

Comment: Note that you are mixing non-ANSI style and ANSI style headers. You should just stick with ANSI style. That means declare the port order and types together in a single declaration instead of listing each port twice.

Comment: @dave_59 ok, I will make that adjustment!